# How to run codepipeline from AWS chatbot

Tags: amazon-web-services, slack, aws-codepipeline, aws-chatbot

I'm trying to run `AWS codepipeline` from slack using `AWS chatbot` feature. I've configured a chatbot properly and it is giving me appropriate response when I'm running a command
`@aws codepipeline list-pipelines --region us-east-1`
With this command it is showing me all the configured codepipelines in my AWS account.
However when I'm trying to run a pipeline using

`@aws codepipeline start-pipeline-execution --name dev-pipeline`

I'm getting following error.

`I can't run the command codepipeline start-pipeline-execution because it isn't enabled.`

There's no option I can see in AWS Chatbot to enable this pipeline.
I'm able to run this same pipeline using AWS CLI and its working perfectly fine.
Can someone please give me any pointer to configure AWS Chatbot from Slack to run AWS Codepipeline?

Comment: Can you check the role assigned to your aws-chatbot, does it have access to execute codepipeline?

Comment: Thanks for response. I've tried giving full access on codepipeline to the role assigned to AWS-chatbot. So I don't think it's a role related issue.

Comment: Where did you see that this actually is possible? The wording of the message seems fairly clear it is not.  You can definitely get the chatbot to execute a lambda that can start a pipeline - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/chatbot/latest/adminguide/chatbot-cli-commands.html

Comment: Thanks for Details @RonanCunningham. Looks like Pipeline commands are not yet supported in Chatbot.